# Testing for unread characters in a Python file-like object

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Is it possible to test whether a Python file-like object has charaters after the current read position?

I'm trying to keep a `subprocess.PIPE` flushed to my stdout, so am continuously running `read(1)` on it. I only want to read if there will actually be something there for me to get (otherwise it hangs until something shows up).

Comment: But by default these pipes are blocking, this means that when you do `read(1)` and there is nothing to read, it will automatically block until there is something to read.

Comment: If you're writing code that doesn't have to run on Windows, `select.select` or `select.poll` is very easy, and probably better than anything else. If it has to work on Windows as well, you can write separate Windows and POSIX code, or a cross-platform async event engine, but the simplest answer might be to just spawn a thread that does a blocking read, and signal between the threads with a queue, condvar, etc. So, which approach do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `subprocess.PIPE` is not just a file-like, it is an actual file. As such you can [get its file descriptor](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.fileno) and pass it to [`select.select()`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#select.select) or similar functions.

Comment: `select.select()` doesn't work for pipes on Windows